# Swift HealthKit permission list is Empty in Setting - Privacy - Health

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I'm getting steps from HealthKit.
When the user request get steps at first, Health Access Page appear.
but I couldn't permission list in "Settings"-"Privacy"-"Health"-"MyApp"
The page is empty like below image. but I can find permission in HealthApp. I don't know what the problem is, do you know?

```
func requestHealthKitAuthrization(completion: @escaping(Bool, Error?) -> Void) {
    let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    let healthKitTypes: Set = [ HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)! ]
    healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: healthKitTypes) { (success, error) in
        completion(success, error)
    } // end of checking authorization
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I try many situations, privacy and healthApp both have Auth.