# Unable to access HealthKit permissions for my app in Settings

Tags: ios, swift, privacy, healthkit

I recently published an app to the App Store that reads several metrics from HealthKit. It all seems to be working correctly in the app (permissions screen loads fine and data is being read okay) but when I go to Settings > Privacy > Health > MY APP, there is just a blank screen with no data.

I've seen this bug with other apps (MyFitnessPal, Balance) and a forum recommended deleting and reinstalling, which fixed it for them. But it doesn't fix my app at all.

Can anyone think of something I might have missed that's creating this issue?

Thanks

[image: health kit capabilities screenshot]

[image: entitlements file screenshot]

[image: screenshot of empty settings screen]

Comment: Are you asking right permissions to user?
Do you have the entitlements file configured in your project?

Comment: Permissions seem fine... I've added a screenshot of the entitlements file. Does that look okay to you Eduardo?

Comment: Yes, it is ok for me. Is this screenshot is from the iOS simulator or a real device? If it is possible, insert a screenshot from HealthKit capabilities, please.

Comment: It's from a real device. I've added that screenshot... hope it's what you meant?

Comment: Don't you see your app if you go in Health app -> Sharing Tab -> Scroll down -> Apps?

Comment: Looks like the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70765672/795339)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be addressed in iOS 15.4 Beta 1. Can you try there?

You should also be able to access your apps authorizations from within Health App. Go to Profile View and navigate to your app under the Apps view.